# LSAT questions help needed, where to ask?

Tags: discussion, scope

Where can I ask questions when I need help with the Law School Admission Test ([LSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_School_Admission_Test))? I am trying to practice LSAT questions and I have some problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try asking over at [MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) with the[site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag.

Answer (score 2):

1. Why not [create and propose your own Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974) for LSAT questions?
2. Why not [create and propose your own Codidact website](https://meta.codidact.com/categories/10) for LSAT questions?

You can try to raise awareness of your proposals on https://old.reddit.com/r/lsat, https://old.reddit.com/r/lawschooladmissions, https://old.reddit.com/r/shamelessplug, https://old.reddit.com/r/promote, https://old.reddit.com/r/IMadeThis, https://www.reddit.com/r/anything !

Comment: I highly doubt the proposal would survive the [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) stage. The scope and potential audience regarding LSAT topics are too narrow to get any far in the process.

Comment: Maybe "Admissions Exams SE" or something like that?

Comment: Still a rather narrow thing, and that stack is bound to be hit with DMCA takedowns of the books, but can't hurt to *try*